# How to create and display the simplest text message?

Tags: messagekit

**Hello!**

I just installed the messagekit via CocoaPods.

I try to follow the Quick Start Guide.

Tell me please, how to create and display the simplest text message?

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is approximately as follows.

```
struct Message: MessageType {
//...
}

struct Sender: SenderType {
//...
}        

class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController, MessagesLayoutDelegate, MessagesDisplayDelegate {
    
      var messages: [MessageType] = []
    
      override func viewDidLoad() {
         //...
    
         self.messages.append(Message(text: text, sender: sender, messageId: messageId, date: date))
      }
    
    }
```